# Is every field extension of degree $2018$ primitve?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

The question is whether every field extension $L/K$ of degree $2018$ is primitive; i.e. $K\subset L$ field extension and $[L:K]=2018$ implies $L=K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in L$, true or false. The prime factorisation is $2\cdot1009=2018$. I know at least two theorem that could help me here: the theorem of the primitive element and another lemma about intermediate fields.

> If $K\subset L$ is a finite separable extension (hence also algebraic), then there exists an $\alpha\in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$.

Second theorem:

> Let $K\subset L$ be a finite field extension. Then equivalent are:
>   [$L$ is primitive]$\iff$[there are only finitely many intermediate fields $E$ with $K\subset E\subset L$].

I don't now which one of these two will be easiest to show and I wouldn't know how to do either one of them. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's now 2019, so I think your question is a year late. :)

Comment: @KCd hahaha, you're right! However, this was a bonus question on the midterm of Galois Theory that I took a year ago which I came accross in my archive; so, it was up to date back then. In addition, since $2019=3\cdot673$ in prime factorisation, by the answer below it should hold that also every field extension of degree $2019$ is simple. Voilá, we've solved this year's bonus question too lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any extension of degree $pq$, with $p$,$q$ distinct primes is primitive.

Suppose $[K:F]=pq$, it suffices to assume it is inseparable. Let $S$ denote the separable closure of $K/F$, then $K/S$ is purely inseparable.

Without loss of generality, assume $\text{char }K = p$, then $[K:S]=p, [S:F]=q$. Choose any $\alpha\in S-F, \beta\in K-S$, then $S=F(\alpha), K=S(\beta)$, so $K=F(\alpha,\beta)$, with $\alpha$ separable over $F$. The proof is concluded by using

> If $F(\alpha,\beta)/F$ is algebraic with $\alpha$ separable over $F$, then $F(\alpha,\beta)/F$ is primitive.

I  remember seeing the assertion on this site, but cannot find it at the moment. I can add a proof if someone needs it.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108002/show-that-the-algebraic-extension-k-alpha-beta-k-is-simple-if-alpha-is-s) the link?

Comment: I think I'm very confused here. First of all, the separable closure of $K$ is defined as the set of all algebraic elements over $K$ which are separable over $K$, right? This includes all elements of $K$ plus an additional set of algebraic and separable elements over $K$. Then why is it the case that $[K:S]<\infty$? I would think that $S$ is a bigger field than $K$, so we would write $S/K$ and talk about $[S:K]$. Furthermore, I don't understand why this $S$ cannot be an infinite degree field extension over $K$, if what I said above in this comment is true. Or should I read $S$ over $F$ sep cl.

Comment: Because comments can't be any longer, I continue with one more remark: suppose that it reads that $S$ is a separable closure of $F$. Then again I would think that $S$ is "way bigger" than $K$. Could you clarify more what you mean?

Comment: @ThomasShelby   yes, thank you for finding the thread.

Comment: @Algebear I edited my answer, $S$ is the separable closure of $K$ **over** $F$, the set of elements of $K$ that is separable over $F$.

Comment: I still don't completely understand your proof since it's very compact; hence, a few questions: 1. I understand that you assume that char $K=p$ (otherwise not a field) but why is it then true that $[K:S]=p$ with $p$ prime? 2. Also, why should the index of $S$ over $F$ be prime? 3. How does any choice of such $\alpha$ satisfy $S=F(\alpha)$? That almost looks to me as if you assumed $F\subset K$ to be a primitive extension. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @Algebear   (1) Because $K/S$ is purely inseparable, so its degree is a power of the characteristic. (2) $[S:F] = [K:F]/[K:S]$. (3) Because the degrees $[S:F], [K:S]$ are **primes**, so any element not in the base field generated whole extension. Your concerns will all be eradicated if you have a more consolidate understanding of basic field theory.

Answer (score 1):

Using pisco's notation and considering the original question we can assume that $p=2$. Then $\beta^2\in K(\alpha)$, which implies $K(\alpha)\subseteq K(\alpha+\beta)$ because of

$(\alpha+\beta)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2\in K(\alpha)$

and

$K(\alpha^2)=K(\alpha)$.

But $K(\alpha)\neq K(\alpha+\beta)$, hence the assertion.